# If non negative functions $f,g : \mathbb{R^n} \to [0, \infty]$ are measurable, then $f+g$ is measurable.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

Let $f, g : \mathbb{R^n} \to [0, \infty]$ are measurable. Then, prove that $f+g$ is measurable.

I know that if the value of $f,g$ is finite, $f+g$ is also measurable, but I cannot prove when the value of $f,g$ is in $[0, \infty]$
since I cannot know what I should do.

Please give me some ideas.

Comment: Why not simply note that $\{f+g>c\}=\bigcup_{a,b\in\Bbb Q, a+b>c}\{f>a\}\cap \{g>b\}$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Why does $\{ f+g >c \} =\cup_{a,b \in \mathbb{Q}, a+b >c} \{ f>a \} \cap \{ g>b \}$ hold? I did prove $\{ f+g >c \} \supset \cup_{a,b \in \mathbb{Q}, a+b >c} \{ f>a \} \cap \{ g>b \}$, but I cannot prove $\{ f+g >c \} \subset \cup_{a,b \in \mathbb{Q}, a+b >c} \{ f>a \} \cap \{ g>b \}$.

Comment: @EPA: If $f + g > c$, then pick a rational $p$ such that $f + g > p > c$. Now, $f - p > -g$. Pick a rational $q$ such that $f - p > q > -g$. Thus, $f > p + q$ and $g > -q$. Taking $a = p + q$ and $b = -q$ does the job.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Good point, but your proof is much cleaner, so I'm going to delete my comment anyway so that yours gets more attention.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. I could understand.